# VC++14 template ambiguity between pointer to member and pointer to member function

Tags: c++, c++14

I have problem with function templates using vs14 compiler.
So the following code demonstrates the issue.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Class {
public:
    int memberFoo() {
        return 0;
    }
};

template <class VariableT, class C>
void nothing(const VariableT C::*memberV) {
    cout << "Pointer to member variable";
}

template <class R, class C>
void nothing(R (C::*memberF)()) {
    cout << "Pointer to member function";
}

int main() {

    nothing(&Class::memberFoo);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler lets me know that `nothing` function is ambiguous. When I see the output, it seems to have other behaviour than I expected.
In the first `nothing` function, compiler deduces `VariableT` as `int(void)`. Actually it's not that weird, but I supposed that the second one will be more suitable and will be matched. What is more interesting if you remove `const` in first overloaded function, the program will compile correctly. 
Can you suggest me how to deal with this, please?

Comment: Is your output not `Pointer to member function`? Ah, it seems that GCC accepts this code just fine, but Clang complains.

Comment: Compiler has deduced: `'void nothing<int(void),Class>(VariableT (__thiscall Class::* ))'`

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the problem go away if you remove the `*` from the function overload?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix it by using some handy type_traits, [is_member_function_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer) and [is_member_object_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_object_pointer):

```
template <class R, class C>
void nothing(R (C::*memberF)())
{
    std::cout << "Pointer to function" << std::endl;
}

template <class VariableT, class C>
auto nothing(const VariableT C::* memberV)-> typename std::enable_if<std::is_member_object_pointer<decltype(memberV)>::value>::type
{
    cout << "Pointer to member variable";
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/244d0babd505039a)

The default type from `std::enable_if` is `void`, so the return type remains `void`.

From your post it sounds like the member function template should be instantiated, but Visual Studio and Clang both yell about ambiguity, which I suppose is fair, given `Type Class::*`, you could infer a pointer to member or pointer to member function, assuming that a substitution of `ReturnType()` is valid for `Type` (which is what we're seeing).

So I decided to skip all that and take advantage of the trailing return type to interrogate the parameter directly.

---

### EDIT

**Including text from [link](http://wg21.link/cwg1584) in [T.C.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276828/vc14-template-ambiguity-between-pointer-to-member-and-pointer-to-member-functi/34277447#comment56298379_34277447)**

> Section: 14.8.2.1  [temp.deduct.call]
> It is not clear whether the following is well-formed or not:
>
> ```
> void foo(){}
>
> template<class T>
> void deduce(const T*) { }
>
> int main() {
>   deduce(foo);
> }
> ```
>
> Implementations vary in their treatment of this example.

Indeed, you noticed that removing `const` also removed the ambiguity.

Comment: Could you please explain why both clang and vc++ deduce `[VariableT = int()]`? Which seems to me awkward.

Comment: @T.C. there's a DR, that explains it. Thanks a lot.